# Correct way to handle iOS orientation when not using storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I'm developing an app and I'm not using storyboard (or any xib file).
Xib files looks too complicated and sometimes when adding constraints the app crashes with no reason and it feels like a huge mess (even with xCode reset auto constraints) .
When I'm writing it with pure code I'm getting much better results and it feels much more natural.

Currently I'm adding view and make them relative by using % (for width only)
and it ensures that the view will be 0.5 of the super view width

```
var someView : UIView = UIView(frame:
            CGRect(
                origin:CGPoint(
                    x: 0,
                    y: otherView.frame.maxY
                ),
                size: CGSize(
                    width: otherView.frame.width * 0.5,
                    height: SOME_HEIGHT_CONST
                )
            )
        )
```

and it's works good, for example creating a rectangle with 0.8 of super view width:
[image: before rotate]

The issue is, after rotating:
[image: after rotate]

What is the correct way to handle orientation when not using storyboard? is it possible to bind views size to orientation changes?

Comment: better use auto layout. there you can set a proportional space to the left & right boarder of the superview  if you don't want to use auto layout you have to set a new frame after the orientation has changed . Try this notification for detecting a rotation of the device `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "rotated", name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)`

Comment: Muliplying with 0.5 does not result in 80% :-)

Comment: @HermannKlecker well yea, code is just for the idea of what I'm doing (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "correct" way, as you put it ... or, as I'll call it "best practices" ... would have you using LayoutConstraints, and adjusting the properties on those if needed (versus modifying a property of the frame - such as width - directly).

Depending upon which versions of iOS you're supporting I would recommend you check out the WWDC 2015 videos (specifically those on Auto Layout/LayoutConstraints) and the 2014 videos (updates to TransitionCoordinators, PresentationControllers and ViewControllers).  This will arm you with the basics so you will have a better understanding of which functions get invoked during an orientation, content, size or position change.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing `super` with `superview`. `super` refers to the superclass' method or property. So in your case `super.frame.width` is the same as `self.frame.width` as `frame.width`.

You meant to refer to `superview.frame.width`, I guess.

Comment: yea it's adding a subview inside some  MyCustomView : UIView class

Comment: Well, then you better use `superview.frame.width`

Comment: well it's the same because i'm adding the view to super.addSubview(newView)

Comment: Read a good book about object oriented programming principles. 
You can add it to super.addSubview(newView) which is the same as self.addSubview(newView) (unless of course when you overwrite addSubview which I don't think you did). But super.frame and superview.frame ist NOT the same. Believe it or not.

Comment: I know it's not the same thing, but in my case it is the same thing I'm adding the view INSIDE <----- a class that extends UIVIew so if i'm doing super <--which is UIVIew .addSubView(someSubView) so someSubView.superView and super are the same. +I dont need OOP book thanks for the advice, there's nothing wrong to call super.X to let other developer know that method | property refers from super class and it's not an override or a method inside the class

+it doesn't answer my question at all, ok thank you for the advice for the question I didn't ask.

Comment: You may have noticed by reading my comments that I did confirm super.addsuview is the same as self.addsubview. But super.frame is not the same as self.superview.frame or superview.frame respectively. You may even use super.superview.frame if you insist of referring to super. However, you have chosen not to believe that and I can live with that. Good luck.

Comment: Well, for some reason you have amended that part of code in your question anyway. Fine with me.